# How to change python version in Mac terminal?

Tags: python, jupyter

I installed python3 in my macbook.
but when I open terminal, type which python, it returns

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

So how can I change to the python3 for temporal use? I don't want to change the system default.
The reason why I change this is because I installed jupyter as pip3 and I want to open ipython file, when I type jupyter notebook, it says command not found, so I realise it because the python versions.

Answer (score 1):

To change to python3, you can use the following command in terminal

```
 alias python='python3'
```

you can also add this into `~/.bash_profile` file

Answer (score 0):

Edit you ~/.bash_profile and add the following line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/your/Python/3.6/bin"
```

after that execute this once

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or restart the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Does **bash** report that the command is not found when you enter 'jupyter notebook' as a command?
Pip should automatically make Jupyter available in $PATH but this may not be the case here if 'jupyter' is not a recognised command

**Conversely** if @Kallz's answer was successful then:
If you were looking for a **consistent** temporal environment for Jupyter where Jupyter runs in *version x* and you terminal shell/all other directories run *version y*, then you should refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442959/activate-different-python-version-in-terminal) about pyenv, which helps manage python versions and create Python 'environments'

If you can determine the specific directory location which executes Jupyter (I have no specific knowledge of Jupyter myself to help with this), then you can set a 'local' pyenv for the executing file location and a 'global' env for the version you want to use for shell etc., thus constraining to the correct version for both purposes.

See a setup tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lw-irZyZmcc)